# Problema com eventos e funções sendo executados diversas vezes no código jQuery?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, ajax

Olá. 
Estou com um problema muito sério com uns eventos que são disparados diversas vezes ao clicar em um determinado botão.

Tenho o sistema de gerenciamento de tarefas abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu clico no botão dos status (Que estejam com o status de PENDENTE ou STAND_BY) o botão passa a ter o Status "CONCLUIDO" e cria uma nova atividade para o mês seguinte (Tudo isso feito com AJAX e PHP).

Temos também aquele botão (com um íconte de atenção) que está na coluna STAND BY. Esse botão, ao ser clicado, faz com que qualquer atividade receba o status de "STAND_BY" (em espera) e a  recebe o texto "ATIVIDADE PARADA POR FALTA DE ARQUIVOS". O problema está nesse botão da coluna STAND BY.

PROBLEMA: Quando clico nesse botão (da coluna STAND BY), ele transforma normalmente o status para "STAND_BY" e insere o comentário da  e quando clico no botão "STAND_BY" ele se tranforma no status "CONCLUIDO". O problema é que quando vou fazer essas situações novamente, sem dar refresh na página, ao clicar no botão da coluna STAND BY e concluir uma atividade, começa a ser geradas múltiplas atividades. Ou seja, parece que os eventos começam a ser executados mais de uma vez ao clicarmos no botão. Quando damos refresh na página, tudo volta o ciclo inicial.

Resumindo: Os eventos estão sendo executados mais de uma vez após o primeiro eventos ser executado.

Sei que o problema é muito particular e fica difícil explicar por aqui, por vocês não terem familiaridade com o código. Rodei tudo e não consegui achar uma solução pra isso. Vou deixar o código abaixo e se vocês puderem me ajudar, eu ficaria agradecido. Obrigado!

Segue o código jQuery abaixo: (Vou tentar tirar as partes menos importantes do código).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Chamando Função de Preencher Dashboard
  update_dashboard();

  //Aqui repitimos a cada 1 segundo 

  setInterval(function() {
    update_dashboard();

  }, 1 * 1000);


  //CÓDIGO PARA PREENCHIMENTO DA LISTA COM OS DADOS DA PESQUISA 

  $('#formulario-consulta').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#botao-click-dashboard').val("submit-vindo-do-formulario");
    var formulario = $(this);
    var retorno = inserirFormulario(formulario);

  });


  //CÓDIGO PARA QUANDO CLICAR NO DASHBOARD "RESULTADOS-PENDENTES"

  $(document).on("click", "#resultados-pendentes", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#botao-click-dashboard').val("PENDENTE");
    var formularioPendente = $("#formulario-consulta");

    var retorno = inserirFormulario(formularioPendente);


  });




  function inserirFormulario(dados) {
    $.ajax({
      //dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      data: dados.serialize(),
      url: "banco/pagina-minhas-tarefas/interface-resultado-pesquisa.php",
      cache: false,


    }).done(function(data) {

      var atividades = "";

      $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, valor) {

        //FUNÇÃO PARA FORMATAR AS DATAS QUE VEM DO PHP
        function dataAtualFormatada(parametro) {
          if (parametro == null) {
            parametro = "";
            return parametro;
          } else {
            var data = new Date(parametro),
              dia = data.getDate().toString(),
              diaF = (dia.length == 1) ? '0' + dia : dia,
              mes = (data.getMonth() + 1).toString(), //+1 pois no getMonth Janeiro começa com zero.
              mesF = (mes.length == 1) ? '0' + mes : mes,
              anoF = data.getFullYear();
            return diaF + "/" + mesF + "/" + anoF;
          }
        }


        var vencimento = dataAtualFormatada(valor.DT_VENCIMENTO);
        var inicio = dataAtualFormatada(valor.DT_INICIO);
        var fim = dataAtualFormatada(valor.DT_FIM);


        //CRIANDO AS LINHAS COM OS TD DA TABELA QUE SÃO O RESULTADO NA CONSULTA AO BANCO 

        atividades += '<tr class="' + valor.codigo + '" name="' + valor.STATUS + '">';
        //atividades += '<td>' + valor.codigo + '</td>';
        atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody">' + valor.COD + '</td>';
        atividades += '<td>' + valor.EMPRESAS + '</td>';
        atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody">' + valor.TRIBUTACAO + '</td>';
        atividades += '<td>' + valor.TIPO_ATIVIDADE + '</td>';
        atividades += '<td>' + vencimento + '</td>';
        atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody">' + inicio + '</td>';
        atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody">' + fim + '</td>';


        if (valor.STATUS == "INICIADO") {
          atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby css-iniciado" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
        } else if (valor.STATUS == "CONCLUIDO") {
          atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby css-concluido" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
        } else if (valor.STATUS == "CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO") {
          atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby css-concluido-vencido" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
        } else if (valor.STATUS == "VENCIDO") {
          atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby css-vencido" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
        } else if (valor.STATUS == "PENDENTE") {
          atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby css-pendente" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
        } else if (valor.STATUS == "INICIADO_VENCIDO") {
          atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade colocarstandby css-iniciado-vencido" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
        }

        //botão stand_by do status
        else if (valor.STATUS == "STAND_BY") {
          atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' css-stand-by" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
        }

        //botão reabrir atividade coluna
        atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody"><button type="button" class="btn css-reabrir REABRIRATIVIDADE data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Clique aqui caso tenha iniciado a atividade ou concluido indevidamente, reabrir a atividade não altera a duração de execução da atividade" " name="' + valor.STATUS + '" value="' + valor.codigo + '"><img src="_imagens/reabrir.png"></button></td>';

        //botão stand_by da coluna
        atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody"><button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary stand-by-coluna data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Clique aqui caso você tenha algum tipo de problema que impeça de iniciar ou concluir uma atividade, Exemplo: Não envio de documentação de um cliente"" id="' + valor.codigo + '"  value="' + valor.COD + '"><img src="_imagens/stand_by.png"></button></td>';

        //botão inserir detalhes
        atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody"><button type="button" class="btn css-detalhes" <a class="" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-observacoes"><img src="_imagens/historicotarefa.png"></a></button></td>';
        //botão inserir detalhes
        //atividades += '<td><a  class="btn btn-md btn-primary css-detalhes " href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-observacoes"><img src="_imagens/historicotarefa.png"></a></button></td>';


        atividades += '</tr>';


      });

      $('#registros-atividades').html(atividades);


      //CÓDIGO PARA QUANDO CLICAR NA LINHA DA TABELA <TR> QUE ESTÁ DENTRO DA <TABLE>

      $(document).on("click", "#registros-atividades tr", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var botao = $(this).attr('class');
        $("input[name='codigo-modal-observacoes']").val(botao);

        //Código para tirar e remover background no tr ao clicar nele
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('ativo');
        $(this).toggleClass('ativo');

        var retorno = pesquisarDetalhes(botao);
      });



      //CÓDIGO ENVIAR OS DADOS DO MODAL DE DETALHES PARA O BANCO DE DADOS

      $('#inserir-observacoes').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formulariodetalhes = $(this);


        var retorno = inserirDetalhes(formulariodetalhes);

      });


      //CÓDIGO PARA QUANDO CLICAR NOS BOTÕES, ELES ALTERAREM SUA COR, TEXTO E CONSULTA AO BANCO


      //CÓDIGO PARA QUANDO CLICAR NO BOTÃO 'PENDENTE' ELE VIRAR 'INICIADO' (NO TEXTO, COR DO BOTAO E NO BANCO DE DADOS)'
      $(document).on("click", ".PENDENTE", function(e) {

        $(this).html('INICIADO');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(236, 200, 70)');
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid gray');
        $(this).css('color', 'royalblue');
        $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
        $(this).css('border-radius', '5px');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $(this).attr('class', 'btn INICIADO');

        var estate = "INICIADO";
        var codigo = $(this).val();
        var antigoestado = "NAO_ERA_STAND_BY"; //ESSA VARIÁVEL FOI CRIADA SÓ PARA A FUNÇÃO DE MUDAR STANDY_BY PARA CONCLUÍDO FUNCIONAR. ELA NÃO TEM VALOR AQUI


        var alterar = alterarStatus(estate, codigo, antigoestado);


      });



      //CÓDIGO PARA QUANDO CLICAR NO BOTÃO 'INICIADO' ELE VIRAR 'CONCLUIDO' (NO TEXTO, COR DO BOTAO E NO BANCO DE DADOS)'
      $(document).on("click", ".INICIADO", function(e) {


        $(this).html('CONCLUIDO');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(86, 137, 73)');
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid gray');
        $(this).css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
        $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
        $(this).css('border-radius', '5px');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $(this).attr('class', 'btn CONCLUIDO');

        var estate = "CONCLUIDO";
        var codigo = $(this).val();
        var antigoestado = "NAO_ERA_STAND_BY"; //ESSA VARIÁVEL FOI CRIADA SÓ PARA A FUNÇÃO DE MUDAR STANDY_BY PARA CONCLUÍDO FUNCIONAR. ELA NÃOO TEM VALOR AQUI



        var criar = criarAtividade(codigo);
        var alterar = alterarStatus(estate, codigo, antigoestado);

      });




      //CÓDIGO PARA QUANDO CLICAR NO BOTÃO 'VENCIDO' ELE VIRAR 'INICIADO/VENCIDO' (NO TEXTO, COR DO BOTAO E NO BANCO DE DADOS)'

      $(document).on("click", ".VENCIDO", function(e) {

        $(this).html('INICIADO_VENCIDO');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(196, 95, 49)');
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid gray');
        $(this).css('color', 'white');
        $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
        $(this).css('border-radius', '5px');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $(this).attr('class', 'btn INICIADO_VENCIDO');

        var estate = "INICIADO_VENCIDO";
        var codigo = $(this).val();
        var antigoestado = "NAO_ERA_STAND_BY"; //ESSA VARIÁVEL FOI CRIADA SÓ PARA A FUNÇÃO DE MUDAR STANDY_BY PARA CONCLUÍDO FUNCIONAR. ELA NÃOO TEM VALOR AQUI


        var alterar = alterarStatus(estate, codigo, antigoestado);


      });



      //CÓDIGO PARA QUANDO CLICAR NO BOTÃO 'INICIADO/VENCIDO' ELE VIRAR 'CONCLUIDO/VENCIDO' (NO TEXTO, COR DO BOTAO E NO BANCO DE DADOS)'

      $(document).on("click", ".INICIADO_VENCIDO", function(e) {

        $(this).html('CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(106, 83, 157)');
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid gray');
        $(this).css('color', 'white');
        $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
        $(this).css('border-radius', '5px');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $(this).attr('class', 'btn CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO');


        var estate = "CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO";
        var codigo = $(this).val();
        var antigoestado = "NAO_ERA_STAND_BY"; //ESSA VARIÁVEL FOI CRIADA SÓ PARA A FUNÇÃO DE MUDAR STANDY_BY PARA CONCLUÍDO FUNCIONAR. ELA NÃOO TEM VALOR AQUI


        var criar = criarAtividade(codigo);
        var alterar = alterarStatus(estate, codigo, antigoestado);


      });





      //CÓDIGO PARA QUANDO CLICAR NO BOTÃO 'STANDY BY DA COLUNA', ENTÃO ALTERAR O STATUS DA ATIVIDADE PARA STANDY_BY

      $(document).on("click", ".stand-by-coluna", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var tipo_ativ = 'STAND_BY'; /*$(this).attr('class')*/
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $(this).css('background-color', '#424242');
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid gray');
        $(this).css('color', 'white');
        $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
        $(this).css('border-radius', '5px');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        var codigo_emp = $(this).attr('id');
        var cod_emp = $(this).val();


        $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.colocarstandby").html("STAND_BY");
        $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.colocarstandby").css('background-color', 'black');
        $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.colocarstandby").attr('class', 'btn STAND_BY');



        //CHAMANDO FUNÇÃO QUE UTILIZA O AJAX PARA ALTERAR O STATUS PARA STAND_BY NO BANCO DE DADOS

        var alterarstandby = transformarStandBy(tipo_ativ, codigo_emp, cod_emp);

        tipo_ativ = "";


      });


      //CÓDIGO PARA TRANSFORMAR O BOTÃO STAND BY EM CONCLUIDO

      $(document).on("click", ".STAND_BY", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).html('CONCLUIDO');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(86, 137, 73)');
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid gray');
        $(this).css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
        $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
        $(this).css('border-radius', '5px');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $(this).attr('class', 'btn CONCLUIDO');

        var estate = "CONCLUIDO";
        var codigo = $(this).val();
        var antigoestado = "STAND_BY";



        var criar = criarAtividade(codigo);
        var alterar = alterarStatus(estate, codigo, antigoestado);




      });





    }).fail(function() {


    }).always(function() {


    });



    //CÓDIGO PARA QUANDO CLICAR NO BOTÃO 'REABRIR ATIVIDADES', ENTÃO A ATIVIDADE SERÁ REABERTA

    $(document).on("click", ".REABRIRATIVIDADE", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var elemento = $(this);
      var sts = $(this).attr('name');
      var codigo_empr = $(this).val();

      //PASSAR BOTÃO DE CONCLUIDO PARA INICIADO    
      if (sts == "CONCLUIDO") {
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").html("INICIADO");
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('background-color', 'rgb(236, 200, 70)');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('border', '1px solid gray');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('color', 'royalblue');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('font-weight', 'bold');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('border-radius', '5px');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").attr('class', 'btn INICIADO REABRIRATIVIDADE');

        //Altera o atributo name do elemento
        elemento.attr('name', 'INICIADO');

        var novo_status = "INICIADO";
        var reabrir = reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr);

      }

      //PASSAR BOTÃO DE CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO PARA INICIADO_VENCIDO 
      else if (sts == "CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO") {
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").html("INICIADO_VENCIDO");

        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('background-color', 'rgb(196, 95, 49)');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('border', '1px solid gray');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('color', 'white');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('font-weight', 'bold');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('border-radius', '5px');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").attr('class', 'btn INICIADO_VENCIDO REABRIRATIVIDADE');


        //Altera o atributo name do elemento
        elemento.attr('name', 'INICIADO_VENCIDO');


        var novo_status = "INICIADO_VENCIDO";
        var reabrir = reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr);

      }

      //PASSAR BOTÃO DE INICIADO PARA PENDENTE 
      else if (sts == "INICIADO") {
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").html("PENDENTE");
        //andrews//////////////////////////////    
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('background-color', 'RoyalBlue');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('border', '1px solid gray');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('color', 'white');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('font-weight', 'bold');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('border-radius', '5px');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////     
        $("tr#" + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").attr('class', 'btn PENDENTE REABRIRATIVIDADE');

        //Altera o atributo name do elemento
        elemento.attr('name', 'PENDENTE');

        var novo_status = "PENDENTE";
        var reabrir = reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr);


      }


      //PASSAR BOTÃO DE INICIADO_VENCIDO PARA VENCIDO 
      else if (sts == "INICIADO_VENCIDO") {
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").html("VENCIDO");
        //andrews//////////////////////////////     
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('background-color', 'rgb(165, 42, 42)');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('border', 'px solid gray');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('color', 'white');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('font-weight: bold;', 'bold');
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").css('border-radius', '5px');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////       
        $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").attr('class', 'btn VENCIDO REABRIRATIVIDADE');


        //Altera o atributo name do elemento
        elemento.attr('name', 'VENCIDO');

        var novo_status = "VENCIDO";
        var reabrir = reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr);


      }


    });



  }

  // ---------------------------------- FUNÇÕES -------------------------------------------------------//


  //Criação da função que altera o dashboard
  function update_dashboard() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "banco/pagina-minhas-tarefas/prencher-dashboard.php",
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json"

    }).done(function(retornodashboard) {
      //Aqui atualizamos os H1 do Dashboard com os novos resultados:
      $("h1#pendentes").html(retornodashboard.pendentes);
      $("h1#iniciados").html(retornodashboard.iniciados);
      $("h1#iniciados-vencidos").html(retornodashboard.iniciados_vencidos);
      $("h1#vencidos").html(retornodashboard.vencidos);
      $("h1#concluidos").html(retornodashboard.concluidos);
      $("h1#concluidos-vencidos").html(retornodashboard.concluidos_vencidos);


    }).fail(function() {
      console.log("Erro ao atualizar");

    }).always(function() {


    });

  }

  // FUNÇÃO QUE FAZ O POST DE QUANDO CLICAR NO BOTÃO DE DETALHES, APARECER O DETALHE (do campo da tabela) na DIV id#espaco-detalhes  //

  function pesquisarDetalhes(dados) {


    $.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      data: {
        botao: dados
      },
      url: "banco/pagina-minhas-tarefas/interface-consulta-comentarios.php",
      cache: false,
      async: false

    }).done(function(retornodobanco) {

      var detalhes = "";
      var feedback = "";


      //Aqui abaixo, preenchemos as divs com os dados vindo da consulta ao arquivo php do AJAX

      $.each($.parseJSON(retornodobanco), function(chave, valor) {
        if (valor.DETALHES == null) {
          info = "Não Possui Observações";
          detalhes = "<p>" + info + "</p>";

        } else {
          detalhes = "<p>" + valor.DETALHES + "</p>";
        }

        if (valor.FEEDBACK == null) {
          info2 = "Não Possui Feedback";
          feedback = "<p>" + info2 + "</p>";
        } else {
          feedback = "<p>" + valor.FEEDBACK + "</p>";
        }




      });


      $('#espaco-detalhes').html(detalhes);
      $('#espaco-feedback').html(feedback);


    }).fail(function() {


    }).always(function() {


    });

  }


  // --------- FUNÇÃO  PARA INSERIR OBSERVAÇÕES NO CAMPO DO BANCO DA RESPECTIVA ATIVIDADE SELECIONADA ------------------- //


  function inserirDetalhes(parametro) {
    $.ajax({
      data: parametro.serialize(),
      url: "banco/pagina-minhas-tarefas/inserir-observacoes.php",
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,



    }).done(function(data) {
      alert(data);


    }).fail(function() {


    }).always(function() {


    });

  }


  //FUNÇÃO PARA ALTERAR OS STATUS QUANDO CLICAR NOS BOTÕES "STATUS"

  function alterarStatus(estate, codigo, antigoestado) {

    $.ajax({
      url: "banco/pagina-minhas-tarefas/mudarstatus.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        estate: estate,
        codigo: codigo,
        antigoestado: antigoestado
      },
      async: false

    }).done(function(data) {



    }).fail(function() {


    }).always(function() {


    });

  }



  //FUNÇÃO PARA CRIAR ATIVIDADE QUANDO CLICAR NO BOTÃO STANDY BY E PASSAR PARA CONCLUÍDO

  function criarAtividade(codigo) {

    $.ajax({
      url: "banco/pagina-minhas-tarefas/criar-atividade.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        codigo: codigo
      },
      async: false

    }).done(function(data) {



    }).fail(function() {


    }).always(function() {


    });

  }


  //FUNÇÃO PARA A AÇÃO DE TRANSFORMAR O STATUS DA ATIVIDADE EM STAND BY

  function transformarStandBy(tipo_ativ, codigo_emp, cod_emp) {

    $.ajax({
      url: "banco/pagina-minhas-tarefas/tarefa-stand-by.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        tipoatividade: tipo_ativ,
        codigo: codigo_emp,
        cod: cod_emp
      },
      async: false

    }).done(function(data) {



    }).fail(function() {


    }).always(function() {


    });

  }

  //FUNÇÃO PARA A AÇÃO QUE OCORRE QUANDO CLICAMOS NO BOTÃO DE REABRIR A ATIVIDADE

  function reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr) {

    $.ajax({
      url: "banco/pagina-minhas-tarefas/reabrir-atividades.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        sts: sts,
        novo_status: novo_status,
        codigo_empr: codigo_empr
      },
      async: false

    }).done(function(data) {



    }).fail(function() {


    }).always(function() {


    });

  }

});
```

O Código está bem extenso. Desculpem, tentei reduzir ao máximo.
Desde já, agradeço. Obrigado!

Comment: Primeiro sugiro tirar o "$(document).on.." de dentro de "$(document).ready(function() {..". Depois verifique sua função "update_dashboard()" pode está gerando problemas por está no setinterval. Alguns problemas de requisições múltiplas são decorrente da lógica do código, faça por etapas e vai conseguir chegar ao problema. desative tudo e va ativando, adicionando o código, por parte até achar o problema.

Comment: Obrigado, @FernandoValler . Você diz tirar todos os $(document).on do código ? Em relação a função update_dashboard, já tentei sem ela e não resolveu o problema.

Comment: O problema é que os eventos click estão dentro de uma função que é chamada várias vezes, e a cada chamada gera um novo, multiplicando-os. Os eventos devem ficar fora da função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro da função `function inserirFormulario(dados)` você está criando *event handlers*. Essa função é chamada pelo menos duas vezes:

Aqui:

```
$('#formulario-consulta').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#botao-click-dashboard').val("submit-vindo-do-formulario");
   var formulario = $(this);
   var retorno = inserirFormulario(formulario);
});
```

E aqui:

```
$(document).on("click", "#resultados-pendentes", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#botao-click-dashboard').val("PENDENTE");
   var formularioPendente = $("#formulario-consulta");
   var retorno = inserirFormulario(formularioPendente);
});
```

Cada vez que a função é chamada, são criados novos *event handlers*, como este, por exemplo:

```
$(document).on("click", "#registros-atividades tr", function(e) {...
```

Ou seja, cada vez que você disparar o click no elemento `#registros-atividades tr` irá disparar o click X vezes na quantidade em que a função `inserirFormulario` foi chamada.

O que você deve fazer é colocar esses *handlers* fora da função, porque eles irão escutar o evento apenas uma vez. Resumindo, pegue tudo que tiver de evento dentro da função e coloque-os fora dela.

Comment: Mas @Sam, a função do evento click não é ser executado assim que eu clico no elemento determinado no evento ? Então como apenas clicar em um evento que chama uma função, pode disparar um evento que está dentro dessa função ? Eu lembro que coloquei esses eventos dentro da função porque alguém me recomendou por algum motivo, que eu não lembro. Vou tentar da sua forma.

Comment: Seguinte: cada vez que a função é chamada, irá gerar um novo `$(document).on("click"...`... quando vc clicar no elemento que chama o evento, irá disparar quantas vezes foi gerado o .on("click").. sacou?

Comment: Mais uma vez, obrigado, @Sam. Mas você consegue ver algum motivo plausível para o rapaz me recomentar deixar esses eventos dentro da função ?

Comment: Se fosse pra ser executado apenas 1 vez, justificaria coloca-los dentro da função

Comment: É até uma questão de lógica rs... se eu quero que capture um click em um elemento, pra que colocar a parada dentro de uma função? Até pq, como eu disse, cada vez que a função for chamada, vai multiplicar o evento e 1 click vai virar, 2, 3, 4 etc...

Comment: Uma última pergunta, o Fernando Valler recomendou isso aqui: " Primeiro sugiro tirar o "$(document).on.." de dentro de "$(document).ready(function() {.." " ... Você consegue ver motivo pra ele ter recomendado isso ?

Comment: Tanto faz, dentro ou fora. A única diferença que vejo é que se colocar dentro, o evento só vai funcionar após o DOM ser carregado, mas isso é irrisório, porque o DOM é carregado em fração de segundo.

Comment: Obrigado, Sam. Vou aprovar sua resposta lá. Uma última dúvida. Como fazer para que um evento click só funcione uma vez e só funcione novamente quando a página for recarregada ? Ou seja, quero que o botão só transforme o status da atividade uma vez. Pois quando eu clico no botão da coluna STAND BY, para deixar a atividade com status de STAND_BY ele faz essa ação normalmente e insere um comentário. Porém quando eu clico nele novamente, com o status já estando STAND_BY, é apenas inserido a mensagem. E se eu for clicando no botão, a mensagem é sempre inserida.

Comment: Cara, tente trocando o `.on` por `.one`. Não sei se vai funcionar no seu caso, mas dá uma tentada aí. Senão teremos que buscar outra solução.

Comment: Coloquei, mas ai ele cancela os eventos em todas as linhas <tr> da consulta. E eu gostaria que fosse feito só na linha que eu clicasse. Se quiser eu abro uma pergunta relacionada a isso (se você preferir).

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92518/discussion-between-sam-and-thiago-petherson).